# disable double click on body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to disable double click on body. i try given below code but it is not working.

```
$("*").dblclick(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: The code posted disables double click on any element (use `document.body` instead of `*` to disable it on `body` element only), so what might be the problem? Does “it is not working” mean that some other event handler is invoken on double click? Please post relevant code (HTML and JavaScript) that actually produces the problem, and specify what actually happens. As a basic check, check that jQuery is actually loaded. Use some diagnostic output in your event handler to see that it gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).dblclick(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try like

```
$("body").dblclick(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or even try like

```
$('body').bind('dblclick',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```